# Simple library for charting JS

Tags: angularjs, charts, javascript

I'm looking for a very simple chart library that can do that sort of graph :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy3hY.png

If possible, in JS.
I've tried Angular-Charts but it doesn't really seems to be good for this project...

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking for simplicity try http://c3js.org/

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/ isn't the leanest of libraries but will also get the job done quickly and easily

Comment: D3, the dependency, is quite beefy (151k minified).